# Is it possible to use same JDK for both windows 10 and ubuntu?

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu-16.04

I am having windows machine with JDK 1.8, recently i installed Ubuntu to it(i.e.they are in C drive). Can i use same JDK 1.8 for Ubuntu also ? Or i need to again install from ubuntu command prompt.

Because i checked in ubuntu command prompt by giving `java -version` it is asking me to install the java packages newly.

Comment: nope... you need to explicitly download install those according to the OS... even if they can run on the same machine...

Comment: Thanks @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: You have to be **precise**. Are you talking about using the **same** JVM binaries (as in: you are using the ubuntu that is "baked" into windows 10) - or do you have a real distinct virtual machine with ubuntu that is supposed to run the same *version* of java?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Remember: Windows 10 has an ubuntu subcomponent that is kinda "baked" into windows itself. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide . The integration is much tighter than installing a virtual box for example and creating an Ubuntu image within the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to install it! Just install it with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

And you will have the same version of java machine as in Windows.

Comment: Please note: A) he is asking about the *same* JVM ... I am wondering if he means to use the windows JVM within the ubuntu that runs *within* WIndows 10. B) when you install the windows JVM today, and the linux JVM 2 weeks later, it could well be that the versions do not match up. This is a manual process, so unless you pay attention there is **no** guarantee whatsoever that two JVM installations have the same version!

Comment: May be not so complicated? Nobody knows what did he mean. But he wrote that he doesn't have a JVM in Ubuntu and I suppose he wanted to use in Ubuntu the same JVM installed in the Windows. That's not possible.
And in your case why don't you update windows JVM to the latest version?

Comment: I only gave some suggestions. Given the fact that the OP doesn't come back on any of the input, it doesnt matter anyway.